# Can i use cypress.io for end to end testing with jest instead of mocha?

Tags: cypress

I really like the end to end testing of cypress.io.

However, I use jest. I would like to use jest instead of mocha. Can i use cypress io with jest instead of mocha?

Answer (score 4):

At this moment of writing, it would require some wrangling:

More on this:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/281#issuecomment-387623959

Otherwise, one would have to create custom matchers for jest.

Comment: According to that thread, they are now considering having jest support as a [proposal](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/281#issuecomment-453900898). There is also the [cypress-jest-adapter](https://github.com/phongnd39/cypress-jest-adapter) which can help bridge the gap.